# how to set auto layout for dynamically created buttons?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout

[image] 
  i am creating dynamic buttons and labels with scroll view now i want set auto layout  for that .   hows its possible set multiple dynamic buttons .i search many tutorial but not got any example for set auto layout multiple dynamic buttons.its work but all buttons are set together .means show only one button and label. but i am search its show correct result but auto layout is not work . what the problem

```
   -(void)DynamicButton:(NSMutableArray*)objectName
    {
     for(UIView *view in [scrollView subviews])
      {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
      }
      int yPossion = 100, xPossion = 44; int temp = 0;


      for (int i = 0; i<[objectName count]; i++)
     {
    SMSCategory *cat = [objectName objectAtIndex:i];

    UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [aButton setTag:i];
    [aButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
    [aButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [aButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-menu.png"]  
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [aButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i] 
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [aButton setFrame:CGRectMake(xPossion, yPossion, 70, 60)];
     aButton.highlighted=YES;

    [scrollView addSubview:aButton];

    ;

    xPossion += aButton.frame.size.width+35;
    temp++;
    if (temp==3)
    {
        yPossion = aButton.frame.origin.y+aButton.frame.size.height+20;
        temp = 0;
        xPossion = 44;
        yPossion += aButton.frame.size.width-15;
        [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width ,yPossion-
       50)];
    }

    UILabel *label =  [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [label setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];

    [label setText:cat.Name];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];

    [label sizeToFit];

    [label setFrame:CGRectMake(4, 44, 70, 60)];
    [scrollView addSubview:label];
    [aButton addSubview:label];

   }
   }

   //Autolayout code 
   [aButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"aButton":aButton};

    // 2. Define the button Sizes
    NSArray *aButton_constraint_H = [NSLayoutConstraint 
                                     constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[aButton(60)]"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                         views:viewsDictionary];

    NSArray *aButton_constraint_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[aButton(70)]"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:viewsDictionary];
    [aButton addConstraints:aButton_constraint_H];
    [aButton addConstraints:aButton_constraint_V];


    // 3. Define the views Positions using options
     NSArray *constraint_POS_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-80-[aButton]"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                        views:viewsDictionary];

     NSArray *constraint_POS = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-20-[aButton]"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                       metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

    [self.view addConstraints:constraint_POS_V];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraint_POS];


}
```

Comment: https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout and have a look its example.

Comment: thanks but u have some simple example

Comment: problem is that all buttons set together and show only last buttons but when i search buttons its show correct result . what is the problem

Comment: You would probably be much better off using a `UICollectionView` to lay out your buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the constraints programmatically, similar to how you have with your searchBar code. Did you just copy that code from somewhere without even understanding it?

There are many many tutorials for this, such as: https://medium.com/@jsleeuw/mastering-programmatic-auto-layout-b02ed2499d79

You will need to create all your autoLayout constraints with something like this:

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];
```

There is also the visual format which you already have a sample of in your code.

I also edited your question to clean up the text and to format the code so it is readable. Please note the changes I made to make it easier for people to read your code.

Comment: this code for only single button i know that how to set for single button. i want to set multiple buttons that i am created

Comment: @ChetanGharat there is no difference between multiple buttons or a single button. The code is the same. For each button you need to give it a set of constraints

Comment: yes but i created 83 buttons then every time need to set constraints for that .......

Comment: @ChetanGharat yes, thats how it works. There is no magical fix. If you need autoLayout then each element needs to have its constraints. That is the fundamental aspect of autoLayout that each element knows where it is and how to grow etc. On a side note 83 buttons sounds like way too many, perhaps you need to re think your design, use a `UITableView` and a prototype `UITableViewCell` perhaps?

Comment: can you saw my code i am using for loop to create buttons now i code that u have suggest but its show only one buttons how can i separate ?

Comment: i am add image of screen

Comment: @ChetanGharat PLEASE FORMAT YOUR CODE! there are random `;` in the middle, the braces don't line up and the lines are broken. Its very hard to read! At a quick glance the only autoLayout related thing you are doing is `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` this doesn't do anything connected to positioning the buttons. It tells them not to grow in the default way. You need to remove all of your code that is creating `CGRect`'s and replace it with auto layout constraints per item ... if you want to use autoLayout

Answer (score 0):

With autolayout you have to set in almost for cases 4 things (sometimes one of them are inferred by context):

1. X coordinate
2. Y coordinate
3. Width
4. Height

So, looking at your code, you have this line...

```
    [aButton setFrame:CGRectMake(xPossion, yPossion, 70, 60)];
```

what was suggested before it's not totally wrong. Those constraints are exactly what the above line means. The problem is that you should pin the button to it's superview in order for the superview to define it's width and height. In this case, to define the scrollView contenSize.

So, in pseudo-code you should do something like

```
for each button
aButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"aButton":aButton};
// 2. Define the button width and height
NSArray *aButton_constraint_H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[aButton(60)]"
                                                                options:0
                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                     views:viewsDictionary];

NSArray *aButton_constraint_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[aButton(70)]"
                                                                    options:0
                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                      views:viewsDictionary];
[aButton addConstraints:aButton_constraint_H];
[aButton addConstraints:aButton_constraint_V];
```

After that, you should at least pin the very fist button to Left,Top and the very last button to Right,Bottom.
Something like for each side (example just for top side)

```
NSLayoutConstraint *top = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:abutton
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                           toItem:self.scrollView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                       multiplier:1
                                                                         constant:0];
```

Hope it helps!!