# how to set different image for dynamic buttons in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am creating 20 buttons dynamically in my apps project now i want to set images for each button like not same image will be different for each buttons. I try lot of solution but not getting proper result. I am implemented following code for this......

```
      int yPossion = 150, xPossion = 44; int temp = 0;
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
for (int i = 0; i < [objectName count]; i++) {
    SMSCat1 *cat = [objectName objectAtIndex:i];

    UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [aButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];


    //Label Dynamic Code

    UILabel *label =  [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [label setText:cat.Name];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];

    [label sizeToFit];

    [label setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 44, 70, 60)];
    [scrollView addSubview:label];
    [aButton addSubview:label];





    [aButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [aButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-menu.png"] 
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [aButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [aButton setFrame:CGRectMake(xPossion, yPossion, 70, 60)];
    aButton.highlighted = YES;

    [scrollView addSubview:aButton];

    xPossion += aButton.frame.size.width + 35;
    temp++;
    if (temp == 3) {
        yPossion = aButton.frame.origin.y + aButton.frame.size.height + 20;
        temp = 0;
        xPossion = 44;
        yPossion += aButton.frame.size.width - 15;
        [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, yPossion - 50)];
    }
}
```

}
Please help me to complete that task. I added 20 images on image folder but how to set that image for each buttons its like (can i use settag for this).

Comment: I'm not sure by telling you how to do this helps you at all. This is not a syntax help type of question this is a basic programming question. If I ask you where are you positioning your buttons in this code could you tell me?

Comment: actually i am new in objective-c  only tell me the syntax for that

Answer (score 0):

Don't be afraid to ask if you are new. Looking at other peoples code and learning is how we all get better at what we do. You can find the answer to your question here - [how to set auto layout for dynamically created buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399372/how-to-set-auto-layout-for-dynamically-created-buttons) Hope this helps you